# C linkage function cannot return c++ class when converting cpp to dll

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, linkage

After following some simple tutorial, I want to convert my cpp program to a dll file, however, it return several errors, like

```
C2526'split':c linkage function cannot return c++ class 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>'

C2371'split':redefinition;different basic types
C2491 'split':definition of dllimport function not allowed
C2065 'split':undeclared identifier
```

in pch.h

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#include "framework.h"

#endif //PCH_H

#ifdef IMPORT_DLL
#else
#define IMPORT_DLL extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) //I follow tutor, but I doubt it cannot works if you use cpp when define extern "C"
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
IMPORT_DLL std::vector<std::string> split(std::string s, std::string delimiter);
IMPORT_DLL std::string removespaces(std::string str);
IMPORT_DLL std::string findevent(std::string str);
```

in pch.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string s, std::string delimiter) 
{}
std::string removespaces(std::string str)
{}
std::string findevent(std::string str)
{}
```

I am sorry, I am a novice in cpp and dll,so any suggestion is helpful! Need I rewrite all program to c, not cpp?

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that the application is built with the same compiler, same compiler options, same runtime library options, etc. as the DLL, then `std::string`, `std::vector`, and basically any type that can have differing internals or use heap memory are not recommended to be used as parameters or return values in the exported/imported functions.  Instead, regular `C` (or Windows types such as LONG, BOOL, etc. and pointers to those types) should be used.

Comment: As the error message says, you declare the function as C but return a C++ class instance. This cannot work.

Comment: @thebusybee so how can I declare a c++ function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you please give me some suggestion in how to write a c++ declaration?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie besides, can I use c++ methods, for example string, vector, in my function, while return a c class, like, char, bool, etc?

Comment: C has no classes, just data types. -- Remove the `extern "C"` from the macro. But as Paul says, beware of using different ABIs.

Comment: @thebusybee, Lmao, yes, a data types, I made a mistake, thanks again, by the way, another question is I cannot use any cpp data types in my function, or just cannot return a cpp data type?

Comment: C is C, and C++ is a different language. However, it has some connection.

Comment: @busybee did it means I cannot use any c++ method(for example, including strtok,,strcpy..) if I want to complie a dll file?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your reply again, but I am still confused...Is c++ project suitable for generating DLL files? If I cannot guarantee that the application is built with the same compile.., I would not use any c++ method(for example strtok, strcpy). Or just cannot return c++ datatype like string, vector. If I replace them by char, can I use c++ others methods? -----from a C/C++ novice

Comment: Sorry, you couldn't use C++-specific things.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem? If the reply is helpful, you could mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About C calling C++ DLL, you need to pay attention to the following points:

1.The C++ function interface for C calls cannot contain C++-specific things.

2.When compiling a dll called by c code, extern "C" should be added before the function declaration in the header file to tell the compiler to process the function name according to the c specification.

3.After the compilation is completed, the header file provided for c cannot contain extern "C", which can be solved by using the macro switch, or by rewriting a header file.

Comment: if a cpp function interface cannot contain cpp specific things, what can it contain? could you please give some examples, like class or something?

Comment: @4daJKong  Hi, for example, you could use int char, something that exists in C language, but you could not use string, it only exists in C++. On the other hand, in C language, there is no class, only struct, about [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/struct-cpp?view=msvc-170) you could read this document.